# temporary watermark image placeholder when image is missing

Tags: html, image

I want to implement a temporary watermark image placeholder on 'img' tag.

I am trying to display on the UI, a list of products that come from the backend. The data that is retrieved
is an object with text and image properties. It may happen that no image is provided.

Thus, I want to display a watermark image template on the 'img' tag if there is no image returned.

```
<img data-bdd-id='productIconImage' src="data:image/jpg;base64, #{product.base64EncodedImage}" />
```

Comment: I want a solution in JSF 2.2. The question is using CSS only.

Comment: @odarboe The css solution will work just fine. Also, you are not using  JSF2's `h:graphicImage`, so a JSF2 specific solution won't work here.